# Firefox x64 for Windows: why does its installer choose the x86 folder

Tags: windows-7, firefox, 64-bit

I have Windows 7 64-bit.  When I downloaded the 64-bit version of FF, it wanted to install in the (x86) directory.  What's going on? This description from the [FF website](http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/X64_Build) isn't exactly clear:

> Although Linux, Mac OS X and Windows are released for x86-64 OS
>   platform, officially build by mozilla.org / mozilla.com is still for
>   x86 only. This is native 64 bit coded mozilla (Firefox).

Comment: As far as I know - only Aurora and Nightly builds have native 64-bit versions. There are also 32bit versions (x86) compiled and optimized for 64 bit OS. Like Waterfox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This translation into English might help you:

> Although there are x86-64 versions of the Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows NT operating systems, the official build of Mozilla/Firefox by the Mozilla Foundation is still only 32-bit.  The project discussed on this WWW site is an unofficial 64-bit build of Mozilla/Firefox by Makoto Kato.

### Further reading

- Sebastian Anthony(2011-07-20). *[Firefox 8 for Windows x64: Has 64-bit browsing finally come of age?](http://extremetech.com./computing/90546-firefox-8-x64-has-64-bit-browsing-finally-come-of-age)*. ExtremeTech.
- [Bug 471090 — Windows x64 build tracking bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471090). Bugzilla.
- [Where are the Firefox 8 beta 64-bit builds?](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/891421). Firefox Help.